# How do I search for a matching string in a datafram using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, date

I am a beginner coder using the pandas library in Python. I currently have a code that reads a csv file pulled from my desk top depending on the title I provide the program:

```
string = input("Enter a ticker: ")
file = string + (".csv")
file_location = 'M:\\A*************\\r*******\\files\\r************.tar\\tmp\\p*********\\' + file

if config.is_file():
    print(file)
    print(file_location)
    df = pd.read_csv(file_location)
    #print(df)
else:
    print("Invalid ticker input")
```

This allows my user to input a file name, and read the file using Pandas. The dataframe is 2 columns (timestamp, users_holding), and roughly 17k rows.

I want my user to be able to input a date:

```
date = input("Enter a date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
```

and the program will return the row(s) with the corresponding date (timestamp) and users (users_holding).
ex/

```
enter ticker: TSLA
enter a date (YYYY-MM-DD): 2019-08-23
timestamp     users_holding
2019-08-23    15,097
```

If anyone knows how to go about this, please let me know!

Comment: you don't need to search for the string -- you should use proper pandas.Timestamps

Answer (score 0):

```
output_df = df[df['timestamp'] == date][['timestamp', 'users_holding']]
```

Comment: don't use chained indexing. Do it all in one go: `df.loc[df['timestamp'] == date, ['timestamp', 'users_holding']]`

Comment: ```Empty DataFrame
Columns: [timestamp, users_holding]
Index: []

Answer (score 0):

Your user given date can be received  as variable dt

```
#Import libraries and and convert user given date to datetime:
from datetime import datetime
dt1 = datetime.strptime("2019-08-23", "%Y-%m-%d")\

#Do similar conversion for your Date column in pandas DF
#Filter all the dates equal to your date
df[ df['date'] == dt1 ] ['timestamp', ' 'users_holding']
```

On a side-note. Please don't use column names such as 'timestamp' It could cause conflicts in your code.
Please make it a habit to rename such columns to something standard such as 'user_time_stamp'